# Rails simple_form gem order of components

Tags: webforms, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

Is there a way using configuration to make simple_form present in a different order it's components.

**SimpleForm** currently displays this way: `label, input, errors, hint`

**I want**: `label, input, hint, errors`

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot manage it with css you might want bo built/edit a [wrapper](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#the-wrappers-api)

---

For example, in the default simple_form wraper (/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb) I have switched the order of `b.use :hint` and `b.use :error` lines

```
config.wrappers :default, :class => :input,
    :hint_class => :field_with_hint, :error_class => :field_with_errors do |b|

  ...


  ## Inputs
  b.use :label_input
  b.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => :span, :class => :error }
  b.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => :span, :class => :hint }
end
```